# Returning status code and error message from wcf rest service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

Here is some code from a WCF rest web service. Please note the HttpStatusCode

```
public string AddProject(ABProject ABProjectObject)
{
    if (UserGUID != ABProjectObject.UserGUID)
    {
    throw new WebFaultException<string>("Wrong User GUID", System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    else
    {
    //carry on
    }
}
```

In a client that consumes the service I have this:

```
string serviceResponse;
try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
    string statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    serviceResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    serviceResponse = ex.Message();
}
```

In the situation above - in the client - the string statusCode contains "OK" and the string serviceResponse contains "Wrong User GUID".

But, of course, that is not right in the sense that I am using Status Code 200 (OK) to pass what is actually an error message.

So, if I change this line in the rest service to ...

```
throw new WebFaultException<string>("Wrong User GUID", System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

... now, in the client, as soon as I 'try' an exception is thrown and caught in the Catch block. Now the string serviceResponse contains "{"The remote server returned an error:(401)Unauthorized."}

If I need to return a 401 or 500 status code - how can I return a more meaningful message as well?